# powershell forcing ssl version 3 for get requests

Tags: powershell

I am wondering if one of the powershell, C# gurus can please shed some light on the how to force Sslv3 during a webrequest on Windows using [System.Net.WebRequest]

I would like to convert the following C# code to Powershell's equivalent:

```
 ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Ssl3;
```

I tried adding the following code to my script but get and error that the term "Net.SecurityProtocolType.ssl3" is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, scriptfile, function. Below is what I used in my code:

```
 [System.Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol = Net.SecurityProtocolType.ssl3
```

Thanks for all the help!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Enumerations require the extended type square bracket syntax:

```
 [Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol = [Net.SecurityProtocolType]::ssl3
```

You could also just let PowerShell cast it for you:

```
[Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol = 'ssl3'
```

Comment: Slightly shorter way using a string: `[Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol = 'Ssl3'`

Comment: While I needed to force TLS 1.2 this answer was helpful in finding my solution, thanks!

The BigCommerce API requires TLS 1.2 and I was getting the following error in PowerShell.

System.Net.WebException: The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a send. ---> System.IO.IOException: Authentication failed because the remote party has closed the transport stream.

Comment: How can I print out all available protocols?

Comment: All protocols are listed on https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.securityprotocoltype